# video youtube in class responsive

Tags: html, css, youtube, responsive-design

hi i have this web site  bit.ly/1EfgOsM , i want the video box with youtube video is allineate with the box image, the width of image box is 40% so also the videobox i want is responsive with of width 40% , the video box i'ts in another class respect to imagebox because imgagebox have a ajax function separated

how allineate the video  ??

view image please http://s22.postimg.org/5ayakawch/tst_Kid.png

i try with this code, the width is good but the height it's more big

```
<div class="video44"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mZXkhXcZ3AQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>



.video44 { width: 40%; 
    font-family: 'Raleway_Medium';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.video44  {             
    height: auto; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
}
.video44  iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please give you code sample , that will be better.

Comment: i insert the code i first post, please view the site

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the `padding-bottom`

To maintain a ratio of a **100% wide div** we need to set the padding-bottom as 56.25% (9/16)....

But our parent div **isn't** 100% wide...it's 40% wide so we need to calculate that number again

Thus **56.25 / (4 * 10)** give us **22.5** but we don't actually need to do that ourselves because we can use `calc`.

```css
.video44 {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: 'Raleway_Medium';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.video44 {
  /*padding-bottom:56.25%;*/
  /* padding needs adjusting to maintain aspect ratio */
  /* 16:9 = 56.25 when 100% wide.
  /* 40% wide would be 56.25 * 4/10 = 
*/
  padding-bottom: calc(56.25% * (4 / 10));
}
.video44 iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="video44">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mZXkhXcZ3AQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks function with desktop, but with this code not show the video in tablet and mobile, why ?